# TypeError: Cannot read property 'authService' of undefined with TypeDi

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, typedi

I create a class AuthRouter:

```
import { Router } from 'express'
import Container, { Service } from 'typedi'
import AuthenticationController from './index'

@Service()  
class AuthenticationRouter {
  constructor (private readonly authenticationController: AuthenticationController) {}

  getRouter () {
    const router = Router()
    router.get('/auth/url', this.authenticationController.getAuthUrl)

    return router
  }
}

const authRouter = Container.get(AuthenticationRouter)
const routes = authRouter.getRouter()

export default routes
```

AuthController.ts:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { Service } from 'typedi'
import AuthenticationService from './authentication-service'

@Service()
class AuthenticationController {
  constructor (private readonly authService: AuthenticationService) {}

  async getAuthUrl (req: Request<{}, {}, {}, {redirect: string}>, res: Response) {
    return res.redirect(this.authService.generateAuthenticationUrl(req.query.redirect))
  }

  
}

export default AuthenticationController
```

AuthenticationService:

```
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library'
import { google, oauth2_v2 } from 'googleapis'
import { Service } from 'typedi'


@Service()
class AuthenticationService {
  private oauth2Client: OAuth2Client;
  private auth: oauth2_v2.Oauth2
  constructor () {
    this.oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2({
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI
    })
    this.auth = google.oauth2({
      version: 'v2',
      auth: this.oauth2Client
    })
  }

  generateAuthenticationUrl (redirect: string) {
    const url = this.oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
      access_type: 'offline',
      state: redirect || '/'
    })
    return url
  }

}

export default AuthenticationService;
```

When I run the server, I got this error:

```
(node:4470) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'authService' of undefined
```

I declared the container for the authenticationRouter but I think the AuthController is not injected.
How can I fix that?

Comment: please show the code of class AuthenticationService, is it exported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updatedt the getRouter method to fix the issue:

```
getRouter () {
    const router = Router()
    router.get('/google/url', (req: Request<{}, {}, {}, {redirect: string}>, res) => this.authenticationController.getAuthUrl(req, res))

    return router
  }
```